# Where is the StackExchange system time visible?

Tags: discussion

It appears that the system time for StackExchange is based on a server in a different time zone from myself.   Where is this visible?

Comment: SE runs on GMT/UTC.

Comment: See also: [What time is it?](http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/what.html) and [Dates: Relative or Absolute?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/dates-relative-or-absolute/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything at StackExchange runs on a straight UTC clock. You can see the current UTC time in the drop down menu when you hover over your name at the top of the screen, bottom left corner: `UTC Time HH:MM`

All time based actions (such as the concept of a "day" as imposed by the per-day rep cap) operate on this clock irrespective of your current time zone, turning the page at 2400 hours UTC.

Comment: does 2400 hours UTC ever arrive?

Comment: Not exactly, but I believe most time processing libraries understand it to be synonymous with 0000 hours of $day+1.